# How to associate a SATA HBA to a Physical Disk

Tags: c#, wmi

I am, admittedly, very new to the whole WMI "thing". This "thing" is quite overwhelming and I'm not finding an answer to the question that I have at this point.  I've found the best information for the drives in my system using `Win32_DiskDrive`. The `PNPDeviceID` field even seems to encode the Port # that the particular SATA drive is connected to for its HBA. However, how can I link a particular drive to its HBA?  None of the fields in the `Win32_DiskDrive` class seem to contain this information. I know that it's attached to the Intel HBA on my MB. For example, the `PNPDeviceID` field for my boot disk:

```
PNPDeviceID IDE\DISKWDC_WD2500AAKS-00L9A0___________________0956____\6&C07A520&0&0.1.0
```

It's interesting to me that the WMI classes identify this drive as an IDE drive since it's SATA, but I don't much care about that. What's more interesting is, how do I map this drive to its HBA? Is there a WMI class that has the particular field I'm interested in?

As an additional question, in the above text, how do I interpret the values after that second `\` character?

Comment: Migrators, please explain how correct use of the Device Manager API belongs on the "hardware and power users" site!

Answer (score 0):

You have to look at the Parent.  I'm not sure how that's exposed in WMI, but the device manager API provides `CM_Get_Parent`.

Comment: thank you for the pointers.  As I mentioned, I'm quite new to this.  Can you provide an example of how to make use of this?  I'm looking on whatever I've been able to find thus far, but I'm not entirely sure of all I need.  It looks like a foregone conclusion that I'm going to have to P/Invoke a good deal of stuff.

Answer (score 0):

CIM_ControlledBy should give you the controller as Antecedent when the Dependent is the instance of Win32_PNPEntity with the given PNPDeviceID, i.e.

```
select DeviceID from Win32_PNPEntity where PNPDeviceID = '...'
associators of {Win32_PNPEntity.DeviceId = '...'} where AssocClass = CIM_ControlledBy
```